# Download file in Ruby that redirects to URL with spaces

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I'm trying to download a set of images, having their URLs supplied. Some of the URLs redirect to ones that contain spaces, which causes OpenURI to raise an error.

i.e. I'm supplied with `http://www.example.com/upload/comercial%20(2).jpg` that redirects to `https://www.example.com/upload/comercial (2).jpg`. This raises an error in the code responsible for the download:

```
url = 'http://www.example.com/upload/comercial%20(2).jpg'
download = open(url, {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, allow_redirections: :all})

OpenURI::HTTPError: 302 Redirect (Invalid Location URI)
```

Is there a way to make the OpenURI to understand the redirect?

**Observation:**
The resulting redirect URL can be correctly handled by OpenURI after encoding the spaces like so:

```
redirected = 'https://www.example.com/upload/comercial (2).jpg'
encoded = URI.escape(redirected) 
# https://www.example.com/upload/comercial%20(2).jpg

download = open(encoded, {ssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, allow_redirections: :all})
# Success
```

Obviously the redirect URL is unknown until the call with `open()` is made.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko please check my edit - the redirect URL is not known beforehand. The question is how to download the file with a single `open()` call, regardless of the supplied URL redirecting or not.

Comment: FWIW the problem is here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/52c738408e7624d1f6ebb8c62a7497fed2684bf5/lib/open-uri.rb#L356-L360 When OpenURI hits a redirect, it calls `URI.parse` on the URL. `URI.parse` adheres to [RFC-3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), which does not allow spaces. If you want to use OpenURI I can't think of a better solution than Sergio's below.

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is handle redirects manually, by using `redirect: false` option and rescuing from the redirect exception (which open-uri raises when it gets a redirect response and it's not allowed to perform it). Then you encode the url and try again. Something like this:

```
begin
  open(uri, redirect: false)
rescue OpenURI::HTTPRedirect => redirect
  uri = redirect.uri # assigned from the "Location" response header
  escaped = URI.escape(redirected) 
  open(escaped, redirect: false)
end
```

You can hide this logic in a method and it'll be "one call" to its callers. Abstraction is good.

Comment: @JordanRunning: `OpenURI::HTTPRedirect` is _the_ specific error. In this case, it is raised by open-uri itself because of `redirect: false`. There can be other http errors, not caused by redirects. Those cases will likely require different handling (http 500 from the remote server, for example)

Comment: @JordanRunning: nah, that line of code is not in play here. It aborts [elsewhere](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/52c738408e7624d1f6ebb8c62a7497fed2684bf5/lib/open-uri.rb#L221-L223).

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev. I would potentially need to put it in a loop to handle multiple redirects and at the same time limit the number of redirects to avoid infinite loop. Apart from that I wonder if there is a solution that would avoid handling exceptions for control flow.

Comment: @mrt: with open-uri you can't avoid using exceptions this way (that's how it works). But you may have better experience with other libraries.

Comment: @mrt: might be worth taking a look at using Net::HTTP directly, the ruby docs actually have a pretty good example of doing the redirect limiting and response parsing without exceptions: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Following+Redirection

Comment: This does not work for me, and most likely never did, because the `HTTPError` is raised before the `HTTPRedirect` error from `redirect: false`. ([cf.](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/0e2ba8495e7cd7bc8081013e115f40fbe96496c5/lib/open-uri.rb#L372)). :(